# pandas rolling sum of two rows before and after

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering how to get the rolling sum of two rows before, itself, and two rows after.

## My Attempt

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1,7)},index=range(1,7))

df['new'] = 0
for i in range(-2,2+1):
    df['new'] += df.A.shift(i)

df
```

## Output

```
   A  new
1  1     NaN
2  2     NaN
3  3    15.0
4  4    20.0
5  5     NaN
6  6     NaN
```

## Question

My above works and gives CORRECT answer, but to calculate mean, I have to divide by 5 and its not much generalizable. Is there any built-in methods or better alternatives to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have `rolling`

```
df.A.rolling(5,center=True).mean()
Out[257]: 
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    3.0
4    4.0
5    NaN
6    NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64
```